# Check if Linked list<Node<T>> contains a certain node

Tags: c#, graph, linked-list

I am implementing a Graph using c# and I want to check if I inserted the same edge twice so that I can throw an exception on doing that.

My Class name is Graph

Here is my declaration of _adjacencyList

```
 protected virtual Dictionary<T, LinkedList<Node<T>>> _adjacencyList { get; set; }
```

Here is my Node Class

```
 class Node<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public double speed { get; set; }
    public double time { get; set; }
    public double distance { get; set; }
    public T source { get; set; }
    public T destenation { get; set; }

    public Node() { }
    public Node(T SOURCE, T DESTENATION, double SPEED, double DISTANCE)
    {
        this.source = SOURCE;
        this.destenation = DESTENATION;
        this.speed = SPEED;
        this.distance = DISTANCE;
        this.time = this.distance / this.speed;
    }
}
```

Here is my addEdge function that takes source vertex and destination vertex 
and values"Weight"  of Edge

```
public void addEdge(T source, T Destenation, double speed, double Distance)
    {
        if (_adjacencyList.Count <= 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("addEdge: There are no Vertices in Graph.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            if (_adjacencyList.ContainsKey(source) && _adjacencyList.ContainsKey(Destenation))
            {
                var sourceEdge = new Node<T>(source, Destenation, speed, Distance);
                var destenationEdge = new Node<T>(Destenation, source, speed, Distance);

                if (_adjacencyList[source].Contains(sourceEdge) || _adjacencyList[Destenation].Contains(destenationEdge))
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("addEdge: Edge already exists in Graph.\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    _adjacencyList[source].AddLast(sourceEdge);
                    _adjacencyList[Destenation].AddLast(destenationEdge);

                    ++_edgeCount;
                }


            }
            else
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException("addEdge : Source or Destenation Vetrtex Don't Exist in Graph.\n");
            }
        }

    }
```

When I write this code in main it doesn't throw the exception of "Edge already exists in Graph."

```
   Graph<int> g = new Graph<int>();
        g.addVertex(1);
        g.addVertex(2);
        g.addVertex(3);
        g.addVertex(4);
        g.addEdge(1,2,15.0,60.0);//Multiple Edge
        g.addEdge(1, 2, 15.0, 60.0);//Multiple Edge
        g.addEdge(1, 3, 5.0, 40.0);
        g.addEdge(2,3,1.0,10.0);
        g.addEdge(4,1,2.0,8.0);
```

What is wrong with my implementation and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you have forgotten to override the `Equals` method for class `Node`.

You need something like the following implementation:

```
public class Edge<T> 
{
    public double Speed { get; }
    public double Time { get; }
    public double Distance { get; }
    public T Source { get; }
    public T Destination { get; }

    public Edge(T source, T destination, double speed, double distance)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        if (destination == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(destination));
        if (Math.Abs(speed) < 1E-9) throw new ArgumentException("speed must greater than zero", nameof(speed));
        if (Math.Abs(distance) < 1E-9) throw new ArgumentException("distance must greater than zero", nameof(speed));

        Source = source;
        Destination = destination;
        Speed = speed;
        Distance = distance;
        Time = Distance / Speed;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is Edge<T> objAsEdgeT))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return Math.Abs(Speed - objAsNodeT.Speed) < 1E-9
               && Math.Abs(Time - objAsNodeT.Time) < 1E-9
               && Source.Equals(objAsNodeT.Source)
               && Destination.Equals(objAsNodeT.Destination);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 13;
            hash = (hash*7) + Speed.GetHashCode();
            hash = (hash*7) + Time.GetHashCode();
            hash = (hash*7) + Source.GetHashCode();
            hash = (hash*7) + Destination.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

Some notes:

- Naming is of paramount importance. The class `Node` represents essentially an edge. So the `Edge` would be a more appropriate class name. Think about the opposite, how difficult would be for someone to read and actually understand a piece of code related with the nodes of a graph, and the name we have selected is edge.
- Try to use common coding styles, in order your code to be more readable. For instance for properties we use [Pascal Case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions).
- You don't need public setters in this case.
- You don't need the default constructor. Would what have been the meaning of someone calling `new Edge<int>()` ? Let alone that you will get an exception since all the properties would get the corresponding default values (double -> 0) and the division Distance/ Speed would result in a division with zero...
- Inside the constructor we have to verify that the values we get are meaningful. Otherwise we will have an object in meaningless state at best. We can't have an edge without nodes ! So `null` is not a valid value for neither source nor destination. Furthermore `distance` and `speed` should be greater than zero. Even if `speed` had some meaning, the division of `distance` and `speed` would have been without meaning - let alone the exception...

Answer (score 3):

The reason is indeed because you did not implement the Equals method for class Node, I'm here to explain also why.

In order to understand why you need the Equals method you need to understand how the LinkedList class works, which is quite simple you just add and later on remove objects of type Node in it. SO far so good but as you're using this object in this block of code
`if (_adjacencyList[source].Contains(sourceEdge) ...)
 {
      throw new InvalidOperationException("addEdge: Edge already exists in Graph.\n");
 }`
you call the method Contains. Now your LinkedList object has to look into the data that it holds and tries to compare if given entry is already in the list, unfortunately nowhere it is mentioned how to do this so it doesn't know what to do. Good thing the folks who created the LinkedLists thought about this and said: let us have a common way to check if two objects of whatever data type are equal and this is how the famous Equals method was born.
Now you are entitled to say, wait a minute, isn't Equals defined by default for every class? Well you're absolutely right, it is, but also kind of wrong, the dafault implementation of the Equals method is no good for us since it checks the objects references and compares them. Even if you create the 2 objects with the same data they will have different references and the Equals method on them would fail (obviously).

Moving on with the linked list story, the linked list will use the default implementation of the Equals method which fails and that is why you will miss the multiple edge case.

Comment: since you addressed first the why part, you definitely deserve a +1.

Comment: What about [How to check if a graph node is in destination in LinkedList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62342368/how-to-check-if-a-graph-node-is-in-destination-in-linkedlist)?